# wooden wheel cribs - car stands

Tags: glue, plywood, mdf

I have some overstock of some baltic birch plywood and 1" MDF and I'd like to make some wood cribs similar to the ones in [this forum](https://www.stevesnovasite.com/threads/diy-wood-wheel-cribs-car-stands.672153/)

[image]

My intention is to sandwich a 12"x12"x1" piece of my MDF with my ply.  Is face gluing these surfaces with Titebond original a good option?

Since these will live in the garage, I'd like to properly seal them as well.  I live in a 4 season climate, so humidity will be a problem as well as the occasional splashing of water when washing cars or if it's a windy rainy day.

Here is a picture of how I envision the cribs to look.  They will be in the neighborhood of 4" tall, so I will likely build 3 units per each of the 4 tires.  This way I won't be lifting each tire 12" at a time.  This also presents another potential safety concern, stacking 3 of these 12"x12"x4" units on top of each other, any suggestions on locking them in to keep the flat surfaces from sliding under load?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE. Please take the [tour] if you have not already. Note that one of the main differences between SE sites and threaded forums is that we aim to build a collection of useful Q&A for future visitors. To this end, asking multiple questions isn't a good fit. Please [edit] this question to ask the single question you would like answered. Followup questions can be posed now or as you progress through your project.

Comment: That all being said, this is teetering on the edge of being off-topic for woodworking; there is very little carpentry or woodwork involved here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This would not be an ideal use for plywood, even good quality birch ply. Ply, in common with all such laminated material, is compressible (and you might be surprised at just how much). Much better to make these from solid wood given the weight they'll be asked to support.

Comment: I see @jdv beat me to it, I was going to say that additionally there are two separate queries here and if you want to ask here you need to separate them, one per Question.

Comment: Sounds good, I was attempting to compare my inquiry like going to the doctor and giving him all my symptoms at once instead of multiple trips as he/she's trying to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think I'll start with the supporting of the car portion, if it's not a good idea, then there is no need to ask how to glue up or how to seal for moisture protection.  Can properly secured pieces of plywood and MDF support the weight of a 3000 pound car?  The intent is to raise the car high enough to comfortably and safely place the wheels/tires on the cribs, made of plywood and MDF?

Comment: @indychuck if that (your most recent comment) is the question you'd like to ask, then please [edit] your question to ask that. Be aware, though, that Graphus has addressed that in his first comment.

Comment: Additionally, with the price of lumber in today's market, especially the price of Baltic Birch plywood, you'd probably be better off using some (relatively) cheap 2x4 (as in the picture) to make the cribbing and save the plywood for something that really needs it.

Comment: good idea, thank you.

Comment: I'll point out that that picture they didn't even bother to remove the stapled stickers from the ends -- there is no finish and it is easy to see why. In most cases it just isn't useful for utility pieces like this. They are going to get dirty and oily no matter what you do, and there is little most finishes can do to protect against that. If left unfinished and allowed to dry (i.e., not left tossed on wet earth) they'll last just as long with or without finishing.

Comment: Think of it this way: every gearhead I know has a collection of dimension lumber kicking around for chocking and keeping parts off concrete or dirt. It lasts forever, just getting more and more oily and dinged up, but structurally fine for literally years. You don't even need to use PTL for this, but if you do have PTL left over that would be ideal. Find a tradesperson near you and ask for offcuts. I bet you can get it for free over the summer.

Comment: Actually... any oil or grease that may soak into the wood will act as a preservative, or at a minimum, a water repelling coating.

Comment: I just noticed the "locking" part of the question. Make a tab that attaches to the inside bottom of each "lift" and extends down below it. When you stack them, the "tab" fits inside the lift below to keep them from sliding on each other while the weight of the car settles on it. The bottom one wouldn't have any, each of the middle & top ones would. I would put one on each of the 4 sides, centered, to ensure they don't slide around. By centering the tabs, that allows them to stand without tipping when placed on the floor without the base unit in place.